# How should I label and interpret cumulative probability graphs

Tags: probability, distributions, data-visualization, interpretation, quantiles

I've used R's empirical cumulative distribution function (ecdf) to generate a chart that shows the cumulative probability of some cost data.  I want to know if the heading of the chart is correct or can I look at it as a percentile chart?  For example, could I say that 66% of members spend $500 or less with a heading like "FY 13/14 Percentage of members that incur costs at or below the specified value".

[image]

Comment: You got it! I wonder if flipping the axes will be more informative for your audience, but that's just a matter of swapping the arguments to `plot`.

Comment: Thank you.  Could I change the y-axis label to "Percentage", to relate it to the main heading, which is "FY 13/14 Percentage of members that incur costs at or below the specified value"

Comment: "Percentage of what?" I would wonder.

Comment: Percentage of Members

Comment: Probability ranges from 0 to 1, percent from 0 to 100%. You can change what you like so long as the axis title (label) and values are consistent. I am with Dave: I prefer values on the vertical axis and probability on the horizontal axis (quantile plot).